# #cgo LDFLAGS: cannot find lib files

Tags: go, cgo

On Windows 64 bit i have a simple go program with following cgo statement.

```
/*
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L./lib -ltuser.lib
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
*/
import "C"
```

The tuser.lib is a lib file for the Windows DLL and is the folder same as the go file.
When I build the go code I see the error:  cannot find -ltuser.lib.

Any suggestion as to what changes need to be made in order to make this work.

Comment: Can you post the exact error seen to the question?

Comment: Removed .lib and the new statement is #cgo LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR} -ltuser

Seeing undefined reference to `__imp_TestFunc'

Here TestFunc is the function inside DLL being called from Go program.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked:

```
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L./ -ltuser.dll
```

So it seems that it should be a `dll` instead of a `lib`.